# How to do non-blocking writes to hdf5 file in python

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

Currently we are using pandas to write/append data frames out to `.h5` files using code something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
store = pd.HDFStore(<path>)
store.put(<table name>, data_frame, format='table', append=True, data_columns=True)
```

Is there a non-blocking equivalent where we can attach callbacks for when the write succeeded or failed? Something like:

```
import pandas as pd
store = pd.HDFStore(<path>)
def handler(result):
  ...
store.put_async(<table name>, data_frame, format='table', append=True, data_columns=True, handler)
```

Thanks!